# How to use scaletype of a ImageView as center and matrix at the sametime?

Tags: android, android-layout, scale, pinchzoom

Is there a way to set the `ScaleType` of a `ImageView` as `CENTER` using Matrix ScaleType?

I'm in need of `Center` orientation of an image in the ImageView. Problem occurs when I set the size of the ImageView larger than the screen say 1000dp. By doing so my image sticks to the corners.

If  I use layout_margins, I'm not able to pinch and zoom the image properly.

Please help me find a solution.

Comment: sure: change scaleType to matrix, getImageMatrix(), change it and invalidate()

Comment: It worked.I missed the invalidate().Is it possible to use this technique on a canvas that has pinch zoom?

Comment: sure, no problem at all