# Center the image in ImageView after zoom-pinch

Tags: android, eclipse, matrix, center

I'm using `eclipse`.

> I'm having problem with getting the image in the center with matrix
>   scale type.

I mean that I want to have the matrix scale type and also have the image in the center ...
to put it simply when I run the app for the first time it's image is scale and is in the left side of the screen

I want that when I'm running the app for the first time ..have the image in the center of view with no scales.

Now my first screen looks like this..

[image]

I want it to look like this..

[image]

- have also tied these topics but couldn't find any solution.

[Fit to Android Imageview Matrix Center of Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24381775/fit-to-android-imageview-matrix-center-of-screen)

[Scale and center matrix on arbitrary point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21539949/scale-and-center-matrix-on-arbitrary-point)

[How to use scaletype of a ImageView as center and matrix at the sametime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366354/how-to-use-scaletype-of-a-imageview-as-center-and-matrix-at-the-sametime)

And this is my code...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   private ImageView img;
   private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
   private float scale = 1f;
   private ScaleGestureDetector SGD;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
      SGD = new ScaleGestureDetector(this,new ScaleListener());

   }


   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
      SGD.onTouchEvent(ev);
      return true;
   }

   private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.
   SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
   @Override
   public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
      scale *= detector.getScaleFactor();
      scale = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scale, 5.0f));
      matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
      img.setImageMatrix(matrix);
      return true;
   }
}

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }
```

**Layout  XML :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    android:src="@drawable/gh" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How does your code look so far?

Comment: reduce your image size n try...

Comment: show the xml code @PouyaParakOctopus

Comment: assign `width` to the `ImageView`

Comment: you have given `android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"` that's why it is coming like this

Comment: I added the XMl code @SweetWisher ツ

Comment: @PouyaParakOctopus change `scaleType` to *fitXY* and `adjustViewBounds` to *true*

Comment: So what do you suggest to do??? , I'm a beginner would you plz help me? @SweetWisher ツ

Comment: @MSGadag I have tried it with lots of sizes but all of them have the same issue

Comment: @kaushik in that case i'm not able to pinch zoom my image .... I have to use matrix scale type in order to zoom in with pinch

Comment: what it your screen and image resolution?

Comment: @MSGadag my phones resolution is 400 × 800 and my image is 1024 × 683

Comment: check my editted code im setting img as background not as src try i hope it will work..and im using 1024*600 image...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Better solution is *to make a custom ImageView*

```
public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {

    Matrix matrix;

    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF last = new PointF();
    PointF start = new PointF();
    float minScale = -3f;
    float maxScale = 3f;
    float[] m;

    int viewWidth, viewHeight;
    static final int CLICK = 3;
    float saveScale = 1f;
    protected float origWidth, origHeight;
    int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;

    ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

    Context context;

    public TouchImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
        super.setClickable(true);
        this.context = context;
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        matrix = new Matrix();
        m = new float[9];
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                       last.set(curr);
                        start.set(last);
                        mode = DRAG;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (mode == DRAG) {
                            float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                            float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                            float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
                            float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale);
                            matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
                            fixTrans();
                            last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                        }
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                        int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                        if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                            performClick();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        break;
                }

                setImageMatrix(matrix);
                invalidate();
                return true; // indicate event was handled
            }

        });
    }

    public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
        maxScale = x;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mode = ZOOM;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
            float origScale = saveScale;
            saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
            if (saveScale > maxScale) {
                saveScale = maxScale;
                mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
            } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
                saveScale = minScale;
                mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
            }

            if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2);
            else
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

            fixTrans();
            return true;
        }
    }

    void fixTrans() {
        matrix.getValues(m);
        float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
        float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

        float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
        float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale);

        if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
            matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
    }

    float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
        float minTrans, maxTrans;

        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            minTrans = 0;
            maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        } else {
            minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
            maxTrans = 0;
        }

        if (trans < minTrans)
            return -trans + minTrans;
        if (trans > maxTrans)
            return -trans + maxTrans;
        return 0;
    }

    float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            return 0;
        }
        return delta;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        //
        // Rescales image on rotation
        //
        if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
                || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
            return;
        oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
        oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

        if (saveScale == 1) {
            //Fit to screen.
            float scale;

            Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
            if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
                return;
            int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

            Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);

            float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
            float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
            scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
            matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

            // Center the image
            float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
            float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
            redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
            redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

            matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

            origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
            origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;
            setImageMatrix(matrix);
        }
        fixTrans();
    }
}
```

And simply use this `TouchImageView`

```
public class MultiTouchActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TouchImageView img = new TouchImageView(this);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
        img.setMaxZoom(4f);
        setContentView(img);
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

[Refer this to get more info](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/multi-touch-panning-pinch-zoom-image-view-in-android-using/)

## Update:

You can work with xml also

add this control wherever you want in the xml file

```
<com.example.test.TouchImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageViewMy"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/img" 
    />
```

So you xml will look like :

XML :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.example.test.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewMy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity :

```
public class MultiTouchActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity1);
        TouchImageView img = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewMy);
        img.setMaxZoom(4f);
    }
}
```

Comment: use `android:layout_centerInParent= "true"`

Comment: look at the image ......https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz-YU0FsDfp0NGNjMWNKejdILUE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: again it's not in the center...it's still in the left side of the screen ... https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz-YU0FsDfp0NGNjMWNKejdILUE/view?usp=sharing.......:((

Comment: But obvious, it will be changed as you are changing its position with `Gesture`

Comment: I have recorded a video of my screen ... look at this .. it will hwlp to understand better ..... as you 'll see the image is stick to the left side of the screen ...I want to have it in the middle......https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz-YU0FsDfp0bVZfN3RRRmFnblU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: have u added the tag `android:layout_centerInParent= "true"`

Comment: yes ... my XML is the same as you posted in the answer....I just changed android:layout_width="300dp" to android:layout_width="wrap_content"......But none of them have the proper effect that i wanted

Comment: You need to specify the width..have you ever tried with `300dp` ?

Comment: @ SweetWisher ツ you need to set the scale type to matrix

Comment: Hey I got your problem.. when you zoom it out..the Image becomes smaller than the imageView size and it shows at left side but when you zoom it out, it will be shwon in center.. The problem is O*ImageView is centered NOT THE IMAGE*

Comment: I think thats what i mean...but how to set the image in the center of image view????

Comment: Check ma code. I have tested it and working perfect:) let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: I'm totally newbie and don't know what the ma code is....I would be glad if you can help me with this.....can you post the code that you menshioned as ma code?????!!!

Comment: Check my answer now. I meant MY code that I posted here as an answer :)

Comment: I tried it out....it worked great ... but with this codes actualy the default xml designer page in eclipse becomes unused and if for example I want to add a button somewhere in this image I won't be able ....am i right???

Comment: No..You can use it with xml also :) where ever you want to use it .. I am updating the answer to show you that way

Comment: thank you my friend....It totally solved my problem...i don't know how to thank you ..... thankssssssssssssssssssssssss

Comment: thank you my friend....It totally solved my problem...i don't know how to thank you ..... thankssssssssssssssssssssssss

Comment: SweetWisher ツ - would you mind sharing info how to handle the click to calculate what location of the drawable (I use a Bitmap there) has been clicked? I understand its a calculation based on last.x, savescale and some other factors yet for some reason have not solved that yet. thanks in advance.

Comment: re: above comment - I believe the solution is to catch the initial scaling being done to fit the image to screen (in OnMeasure) and then the calculation is as follows (using initialScale captured during onMeasure): 

imageX = (clickX-valueFrom_MTRANS_X) / saveScale / initialScale.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  
    android:scaleType="matrix"               
    android:src="@drawable/gh" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  <!-- To take it to center -->`
`android:scaleType="fitXY"               <!-- Fit the Image -->`

Change layot width and height to`wrap_content`

And Crop image as per the screen size. And store them in different drawable folders

Comment: thanks for your answer...But I have to set the scale type to matrix in order to have the pinch zoom....I mean I can't change it to "fitXY" in that case I won't have the pinch zoom capability

Comment: then u need to crop the image as per screen size and put them in different drawable folders @PouyaParakOctopus

Answer (score 0):

set  width = 512 and height = 300. and image as background
 try my code. its working

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" 
android:layout_gravity="center">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    android:background="@drawable/imgg" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thank you ... it was better .... but look at the video that i've recorded/ how can i make it somehow that when I zoom it out i gets to the middle of the screen not the north-west :) of it...https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz-YU0FsDfp0UWZhM21SaEloVzQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: yes...some how !!!! .... there is just one little issue that i mentioned it in previous comment